# "Signature verification failed" error after signing transaction on the client using Phantom

Tags: web3.js, transactions, phantom, signature, serialization

I'm building a transaction on the server using Solnet:

```
var newTransaction = new Transaction();
newTransaction.RecentBlockHash = blockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash;
newTransaction.FeePayer = vaultAccount;
newTransaction.Add(SystemProgram.Transfer(vaultAccount.PublicKey, new PublicKey(userWalletAddress), (ulong)transactionAmount));
newTransaction.Add(SystemProgram.Transfer(new PublicKey(userWalletAddress), vaultAccount.PublicKey, (ulong)transactionAmount));
newTransaction.Add(MemoProgram.NewMemo(vaultAccount.PublicKey, "Staking proceeds"));
newTransaction.Sign(vaultAccount);
serializedTransaction = newTransaction.Serialize();
var base64Transaction = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedTransaction);
return base64Transaction;
```

I'm transferring Sol in both directions as a test. I want to get a signature on both the client and server.

In the browser, deserialize it back in to a solanaWeb3.Transaction:

```
const characters = atob(response);

//create a byte array
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(characters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = characters.charCodeAt(i);
}

//deserialize into a transaction
const transaction = solanaWeb3.Transaction.from(byteArray);
```

This appears to work so far. I get a transaction with my 3 instructions and 1 signature:

[image: debug info about the transaction object]

Next I sign it with the Phantom wallet like this:

```
const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction);
```

[image: phantom wallet with approve button]

Now at this point the original transaction object has two signatures and so does the signedTransaction object. There are some differences in the two objects though.

signedTransaction:
[image: signedTransaction object properties]

transaction:
[image: transaction object properties]

I'm not sure which object to use, but regardless they both throw an error if I try to serialize them:

```
signedTransaction = signedTransaction.serialize();
```

Error:

```
Signature verification failed
  at te.serialize (inpageSol.js:268:84506)
  at Object.success (site.js?v=m-LPXQI9321elyVH3u3T3dgZpTNz3YRC9eNs1QdG94w:48:104)
serialize @ inpageSol.js:268
```

As a test, I tried skipping the wallet signature and the transaction serialized without error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the wallet is replacing the existing blockhash and using its own, which invalidates the previous signature from `vaultAccount`. This may be a Phantom bug, since every example I'm looking at uses this exact model of adding the blockhash and then asking the wallet to sign.

If this is taking a long time, perhaps the blockhash is expiring before calling into Phantom, which is making it replace the blockhash?

Comment: I made a mistake when posting my question. I must have grabbed screenshots from two different transactions. Phantom isn't changing the blockhash.